# "this.<injected_service>" is undefined in jest

Tags: testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have a service file called "A" service

```
@Injectable()
export class AService {

constructor(
    private readonly someOtherService: SomeOtherService
  )

getResult(){
  //works fine normally but prints undefined when i run it throught jest
  console.log(this.someOtherService)
return this.someOtherService.doNothing()
}
}
```

Here is how i am making my testing module

```
const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({

      providers: [
        AService
        {
          provide: SomeOtherService,
          useValue: {
            doSomething: jest.fn(),
            doNothing: jest.fn()
          }
        }
      ]
    }).compile()
```

Here is how I am running the test

```
describe('getSubscriptionDetails', () => {
    it('should return chargebee ', async () => {
      const price = await service.getResult()
      expect(true).toBe(true)
    })
  })
```

The following test fails with the error cannot read property **doNothing** of undefined

Comment: Everything in the test looks fine. You don't get any dependency injection errors like services could not be found, right? Looks like `this` is fine, but `this.someOtherService` is what's undefined

Comment: Hey sorry for the misleading title. Yea this.some other service is undefined and I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong with it. Any ideas?

Comment: I've had this same issue caused by `AService` not having an `@Injectable()` decorator.